# Sound is playing slowly in After Effects RAM Playing

Tags: sound-effects, playback, sound

When I play my composition in RAM Playing, the sound of my composition is being slowed down a lot, so it is completely changed, but in my render the sound plays at the correct speed...

My After Effects version is CS6.
My computer's configuration:

- 12 GB RAM memory,
- Intel Core i5 3.4GHz
- nVidia Geforce GTS450
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits

Here is a recorder video that will help you to understand the problem:

What is the problem? What else do you need to understand my problem, or to help me with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why downvoted???

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked your RAM Preview options?

[image: RAM Preview options]

If auto is selected, your frame rate might be modified. Set it to your comp's frame rate.

Comment: the frame rate is good as it is...

Comment: What's your sound file's format? Can you give us your encoding settings for your final render?

Comment: I can provide you all thr information. But I repeat, I have no problems with the sound in the final render.

Comment: If you are using a sound card try to change the audio settings of AE. Under Audio Hardware, try setting it to System Default Input/Output, if selected, switch the others, I mean try them. If nothing changes, you can purge your caches by selecting Edit > Purge > All. If you are using a compressed file format like MP3, try using a WAV. Actually, I have never met this problem yet, but we can find a solution.